# Sitecore Azure Search read @search.score value

Tags: sitecore, azure-cognitive-search

I'm not sure whether this issue lies within the Sitecore ContentSearch API or is purely related to Azure Search (hence asking here and not on https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/).

I am ordering results using the `search.score()` method as well as other ordering criteria. Is it possible to output the value of `search.score()` within my results for debugging purposes?

When I run queries using postman, I see a JSON property on the returned documents called `@search.score` but when I try to reference this in code from `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem` I just get the exception: "The given key was not present in the dictionary.").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Sitecore Azure Search documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/sitecore_azure_search_overview) the scoring profile is not supported by the provider. This may be why you are seeing the issue.

> Refer to the following list for features that exist in Azure that are
>   not currently supported by your Sitecore provider:
>
> - Scoring profiles
> - Geospatial data types
> - Indexers
> - Suggestions
> - Highlighters

The list of supported fields is also available in the [Azure Search configuration documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/configure_azure_search#_Map_fields). This lists the 'boost' field, but not the score field.